# Select all first elements with specific attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On a form, I have to select all first `<a>` elements with a specific attribute value from all the list items present in the form. For instance, in the below code, I have to select `<a>` elements with the content `xxx` and `zzz` — or in other words, the first `<a>` element with `data-role="modal"` from all list items.

```js
console.log($('ul li a[data-role="modal"]:first'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a data-role="modal">xxx</a>
    <a data-role="modal">yyy</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>abc</a>
    <a data-role="modal">zzz</a>
    <a data-role="modal">xyz</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery I tried is only selecting the one with `xxx`.

Comment: @Xufox Sorry, I lost my internet connection when asking via the Triage review and it didn't show me the updated question & comments when I reconnected.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**.find()**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to get all `a` elements with attribute `data-role=modal` in `ul li` and apply [**:eq**](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to get first for each match:

```js
$('ul li').find('a[data-role="modal"]:eq(0)').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a data-role="modal">xxx</a>
    <a data-role="modal">yyy</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>abc</a>
    <a data-role="modal">zzz</a>
    <a data-role="modal">xyz</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**References**

[.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

[:eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('ul li').find('a[data-role="modal"]:first')
```

```js
console.log( $('ul li').find('a[data-role="modal"]:first').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
<a data-role="modal">xxx</a>
<a data-role="modal">yyy</a>
</li>


<li>
<a>abc</a>
<a data-role="modal">zzz</a>
<a data-role="modal">xyz</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Had the logic wrong, @analyticsninja. See the updated answer now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('ul li').each(function(){
     $(this).find('a[data-role=modal]:first').css('background-color','red');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this may help

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('ul li').each(function(){
     $(this).find('a[data-role="modal"]').first().css('background-color','red');
    });
});
```